# Flutter ios build fails in xcode 10.1 with swift_version

Tags: flutter

I'm building a flutter app. everyting worked just fine. Then I think dart was upgraded and suddenly the build of the app fails with this error:

The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. Supported values are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.

I don't see the setting in xcode and not sure what caused this error. Anyone else seen it?

Comment: Okay I figured out this appeared after adding this package
geolocator: ^2.1.1
removing it also removes the error

Comment: This fixed the issue
https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator/issues/145

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else looking for the solution. You need to have XCode version higher than 10.0 before you can use Swift 4.2.

Open your `podfile` and make the following changes

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks! # <---- // 1st add this right below above line
  ...
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2' # <--- // 2nd add this
    end
  end
end
```

After this, in terminal use `flutter run`. [More info](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16049#issuecomment-382629492)

Comment: Exactly the same changes I did